# How To Set File Type

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

**FIREBASE ADMIN SDK**

I am able to upload files to Firebase just fine, with no errors. I am trying to set the File Type because when I upload images, the "type" is empty, and not seen as an image. My Code is below. As you can see, I am trying to set filetype / content type in the Buffer, and while I am *Not Receiving Any Errors*, the file Type is still not being set.

The File Type should be "image/png", as the file is a png.

```
function uploadImage(req, res) {
const file = req.file;
const name = file.originalname;
const bucketFile = db.bucket.file(name);
const fileMime = mime.lookup(name);

bucketFile
    .save(new Buffer(file.buffer, {
        uploadType: "media",
        metadata: {
            contentType: fileMime
        }
    }))
    .then(() => {
        console.log(bucketFile.metadata)
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: Object.assign({}, bucketFile.metadata, {
                downloadUrl: 
`https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${name}`,
            })
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
           status: 'error',
           errors: err,
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm getting this wrong, but name+".png"? Is that what you are asking or your question is about metadata?

Comment: Hey Cutiko. So, name is already passing the .png as shown as name: 'default-profile-pic-png-3.png',